# How to Add TypeScript Function Overloads in a Different File

Tags: typescript

I have a Typescript Module that wraps calls to a large third party API (names are obfuscated to protect the innocent/guilty).

```
// MyFile.ApiLib.ts
export module ApiLib {
    export function executeAction<TRequest, TResponse>(actionName: string, data: TRequest): Promise<TResponse>{
        ...
    }
}
```

Consumers of this API can create their own "actions", and so I'd like them to be able to create an overload:

```
// MyFile.ApiLib.ts
export module ApiLib {
    export interface TheirRequestInterface { ... }
    export interface TheirResponseInterface { ... }

    export function executeAction<TheirRequestInterface, TheirResponseInterface>(actionName: "TheirActionName", data: TheirRequestInterface): Promise<TheirResponseInterface>;
    export function executeAction<TRequest, TResponse>(actionName: string, data: TRequest): Promise<TResponse>{
        ...
    }
}
```

But obviously, they shouldn't be changing my file.  I can see them wrapping my module with their own that then allows for the typing:

```
// TheirFile.ApiLib.ts
import { ApiLib } from "MyFile.ApiLib";

export module ApiLibWrapper {
    export interface TheirRequestInterface { ... }
    export interface TheirResponseInterface { ... }

    export function executeAction<TheirRequestInterface, TheirResponseInterface>(actionName: "TheirActionName", data: TheirRequestInterface): Promise<TheirResponseInterface>;
    export function executeAction<TRequest, TResponse>(actionName: string, data: TRequest): Promise<TResponse>{
        return ApiLib.executeAction<TRequest, TResponse>(actionName, data);
    }
}
```

But this then means an additional file that has to be downloaded to the browser.  I was hopping they would be able to use a "d.ts" file to give their own definitions, but when attempting to reference both the Ts file, and the "d.ts" file, the "d.ts" file, it doesn't bring in any of the overloads/interfaces defined in the "d.ts" file:

```
// TheirFile.ts
/// <reference path="CustomActionDefinitions.d.ts" />
import { ApiLib } from "MyFile.ApiLib";

ApiLib.executeAction(/* no overloads from the "d.ts" file shows up here */);
```

Is this possible?  Is there an easier way?

Comment: Is there a reason you are exporting a namespace from a module? Is this an existing codebase?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you want is to augment a namespace (previously known as an "internal module") that's been exported by a module (previously known as an "external module").

I would declare it as follows:

```
// ./MyFile.ApiLib.ts
export namespace ApiLib {
    export function executeAction<TRequest, TResponse>(actionName: string, data: TRequest): Promise<TResponse>{
        /*...*/
    }
}

// TheirFile.ts
import "./MyFile.ApiLib";

// This is a module augmentation.
declare module "./MyFile.ApiLib" {

    // Within our module augmentation, we are reopening the namespace.
    export namespace ApiLib {
        export interface TheirRequestInterface { /*...*/ }
        export interface TheirResponseInterface { /*...*/ }

        // We are adding a new overload to 'executeAction'.
        export function executeAction<TheirRequestInterface, TheirResponseInterface>(actionName: "TheirActionName", data: TheirRequestInterface): Promise<TheirResponseInterface>;
    }
}
```

Comment: But TheirFile.ts is still a ts file, not a d.ts, so they'd have to import it, which would cause another file to be downloaded to their browser correct?

Comment: If you don't want the import to be emitted for runtime, you could write something like `import {} from "./MyFile.ApiLib"`.

Comment: I've kept everything as modules rather than namespaces.  I don't understand when to use one vs the other.  Do you have a rule of thumb you follow?

Comment: Looks like I spoke too soon.  I'm getting this error now, but not in VS: Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient.  Updated to 2.3.3 in Visual studio, now I'm seeing the error with modules, changed it to namespaces and it went away. and compiles in VS, but not in typescript 2.3.4 command line... weird...

Comment: Today this isn't working at all...  I can't seem to fix the ambient or non-ambient error.